# How to improve this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

I am reviewing my resume and I am curious how to improve the following sentence:

`Built a Chrome Extension for social recommendations which reduced recommendation insertion by 90%.`

It just doesn't feel right. By recommendation insertion I mean that the time taken to recommend an item was reduced by 90%.

Any ideas how to improve it?

Comment: I'd leave out the second "recommendation" and say *insertion time*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Built I’d use Created.  And I agree with previous recommendation.
“Created a Chrome extension for social recommendations which reduced insertion time by 90%”

Comment: Why would you use _create_?

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think you need the word "recommendation" twice here, it should be obvious what your extension does by context
- The word "insert" may be technically precise, but could be confusing in the context of a resume. I suggest replacing this with "create"

> Built a Chrome extension which reduced the time to create a social recommendation by 90%.